# Android, OpenGL, cube, light and materials (no textures)

Tags: android, opengl-es

I made this very simple example code just for the purpose of this question. It is written in C++, using OpenGL and FreeGLUT. I found Android is not providing most of these functions like `glBegin`, `glVertex3f` and so on... So my question is how to create in Android (Java or C++) an application just like this one, showing rotating cube using materials light and NO textures. I found no article answering this question on the internet, so I hope this post will helps others.

```
#include "freeglut.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>

void initialiseScene()
{
    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.6f, 0.7f, 1.0f);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_FRONT);

    GLfloat lightAmbient[] = { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.5f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat lightColor[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat lightPos[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f, 1.0f };
    glLightModelfv(GL_AMBIENT, lightAmbient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightColor);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPos);

    GLfloat materialAmbient[] = { 0.3f, 0.2f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat materialDiffuse[] = { 0.9f, 0.8f, 0.4f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat materialSpecular[] = { 0.4f, 0.3f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, materialAmbient);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, materialDiffuse);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, materialSpecular);
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 25);
}

void renderScene()
{
    GLfloat s = 0.5;

    glNormal3f(-1, 0, 0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    glVertex3f(-s, -s, s);
    glVertex3f(-s, -s, -s);
    glVertex3f(-s, s, s);
    glVertex3f(-s, s, -s);
    glEnd();

    glNormal3f(1, 0, 0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    glVertex3f(s, s, s);
    glVertex3f(s, s, -s);
    glVertex3f(s, -s, s);
    glVertex3f(s, -s, -s);
    glEnd();

    glNormal3f(0, -1, 0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    glVertex3f(-s, -s, -s);
    glVertex3f(-s, -s, s);
    glVertex3f(s, -s, -s);
    glVertex3f(s, -s, s);
    glEnd();

    glNormal3f(0, 1, 0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    glVertex3f(s, s, -s);
    glVertex3f(s, s, s);
    glVertex3f(-s, s, -s);
    glVertex3f(-s, s, s);
    glEnd();

    glNormal3f(0, 0, -1);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    glVertex3f(-s, s, -s);
    glVertex3f(-s, -s, -s);
    glVertex3f(s, s, -s);
    glVertex3f(s, -s, -s);
    glEnd();

    glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    glVertex3f(-s, -s, s);
    glVertex3f(-s, s, s);
    glVertex3f(s, -s, s);
    glVertex3f(s, s, s);
    glEnd();
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();

    static std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto millis = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now - start).count();
    glRotated(millis / 10., 1, 1, 1);

    renderScene();

    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void resize(int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(90, (double) width / (double) height, 1, -1);
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -2);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void idle()
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);

    glutCreateWindow("Example");

    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);

    initialiseScene();
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On Android, you are using OpenGL-es. This is quite similar to OpenGL 3.3+ Core Profile. The glBegin/glEnd part of the API has been deprecated a decade ago for Desktop GL too..

Comment: @BDL Yes, I see and for over the decade I was not using OpenGL. That's why I asked how to do this actually...

Comment: Its hard to answer this question because of how much opengl has changed. In order to get the lighting and textures, you will need to use shaders. Your best bet is going through some opengl tutorials to get an idea for how the flow works now.